# IndexError: tuple index out of range using Partial Correlation function

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, tuples

I'm using the partial correlation function developed by Fabian Pedregosa-Izquierdo (a MatLab copy of parrcor).

However, I'm trying to apply it to my data I keep getting the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "atd.py", line 280, in <module>
partialcorr = partial_corr(values_outliers)
File "/Users/dingo/Desktop/ATD/MiniProjATD/partial_corr.py", line 50, in partial_corr
p = C.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

My values_outliers is an np.array as follows: https://pastebin.com/AHhwmpTg

The implementation of the partial correlation code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/fabianp/9396204419c7b638d38f

Thank you very much!

Comment: What dimension is the array in your pastebin? It's hard to tell from the file if the array is meant to be an `n x 1` array or an `n x m` array.

Comment: It's a (365,) array. I'm still trying to learn how to properly work with this so sorry if the question ends up being dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you posted expects to receive an `n x m` matrix as an argument. You are passing it an array of length `n`.  To get your data into the right shape, you can do something like:

```
my_data = [1.234, 5.6789, -32.101]
C = np.array(my_data).reshape((-1,1))
partial_corr(C)
```

The `(-1,1)` argument to reshape says to put all the data in the first column of `n x 1` array.